# SVG arrow head to follow line direction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

From the below code(not my code), how can I be able to align the arrow head path to follow the direction of the line?

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { VictoryChart, VictoryLine, Curve, Point } from "victory";

class Arrow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { data, scale } = this.props;
    const last = data[data.length - 1];
    const x = scale.x(last.x);
    const y = scale.y(last.y);
    const path = `M${x} ${y} 
      l 0 10 
      l 5 -10
      l -10 -5
      z`;
    return (
      <g>
        <Curve {...this.props} />
        <path d={path} stroke="black" />
      </g>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <VictoryLine
        domainPadding={{ x: 10, y: 10 }}
        style={{
          data: { stroke: "#c43a31" }
        }}
        data={[{ x: 2, y: 1 }, { x: 3, y: 3 }]}
        dataComponent={<Arrow />}
      />
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/x5m74nzro

Example if you change the data value into:

```
data={[{ x: 5, y: 1 }, { x: 3, y: 3 }]}
```

Then you will see that the arrow head is not looking goodor not following the direction of the line.

I want to achieve something like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Victory](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/) is a handy graphic tool for React, but it is obvious that [VictoryLine](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-line/) and code in codesandbox don't provide any arrow-relative calculations within itself. So, you should write a function which will calculate (using trigonometry) all the arrow points and pass them to VictoryLine. Or maybe somewhere is a library which can draw arrows by parameters and you will be lucky to find it ;-)

Comment: thanks for your comment. I am actually using VictoryLine creating custom `dataComponent` to achieve this line with arrow head. And I was able to convert the code above into react-native. But just need help how to make the arrow head follow the correct direction of the line from the codesandbox and will convert it to RN.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get this at first time, I thought you need a universal tool. Ok, here is my masterpiece of Arrow:     
const path = `M${x+10} ${y+-6} 
      l -11 3 
      l 3 5.5
      z`;
   ;-)

Comment: thanks for sharing your custom path. However the main goal as stated in the original post and in my comment is to have the arrow head follow the line direction. What if the line is now pointing on the opposite direction? Please see the images above. In the codesandbox, I tried to use `data={[{ x: 5, y: 1 }, { x: 3, y: 3 }]}` and your path seems be not in the right direction.

Comment: So, finally, you want a universal tool for drawing arrows in different directions? I told you - there is no way to do it typing a few digits. Every time you change direction or angle (to axis X) of your line you have to recalculate triangle tops coordinates. Tips: 1) make an arrow triangle aligned to axis X at the end of your line 2) calculate angle between your line and axis X 3) rotate the arrow triangle to the angle you got from step 2.

Comment: thanks @Max Kurtz, though im not yet sure how to achieve that. I was hoping that the above code I set as an example would be enough to be modified by someone who can help me to achieve the goal. Im still new working in RN, so still need a lot to learn.